# How to load unmanaged library with P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unmanaged

So i have one old unmanaged library dll/tlb. I want to use it in .net 4.0 program. I have basicly no idea how to do this, so if u can provide me with some tutorial or even better example would be great. i was looking at this:
  [pInvoke, .net 4 vs 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462693/pinvoke-net-4-vs-3-5) but i can't figure anything out. I also checked this out but i don't know what should i be using so it would be working.  http://codenition.blogspot.com/2010/05/pinvokestackimbalance-in-net-40i-beg.html

Thank u all for the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a reference to your library by right clicking the references folder in the solution explorer.

After that in the dialog box that appears you select the COM tab and the Browse, and find your DLL.

The if you want to acces different methods take a look at this example:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int MessageBox(int h, string m, string c, int type);
```

Where the dll between the square braces is your DLL and the extern keyword allows you to specify you are using the method from an external library.

For more reference please read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: well it can't be found it the com tab, and if i try to add it trough browse tab i get an error. A refference could not be added.

Comment: Ok that helps, but one more quastion, how should i use a constructor from that dll?

Comment: what do you mean by constructor, a constructor is used in a class, you only need to use certain methods form the external library not instantiate a class from it.

Comment: Note that PInvoke only works with C dll, not C++. Since C doesn't have classes, there's no constructor to call.

Comment: Ow ok, i'm trying to get one old library to work, so realy pain in the ass, any idea how to get all metods of a dll, and what for is my tlb for?

Comment: its recommended to post each question as a different one, if this helped, marked it as answered and post a new one, also a bit of research never hurts.